# Is wchar_t needed to support unicode when using the WinApi?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, unicode

I am aware that normally you do not need `wchar_t` to support unicode for general purpose code, however, the Windows API seems to have a ASCII or Wide Character equivalent of all methods that take a string. For example:

```
FindWindowA(nullptr, "File Explorer");  // ASCII version
FindWindowW(nullptr, L"File Explorer"); // Wide Character version
```

I compile with `Visual Studio 2017` using the following option in `Properties > General`:

```
Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set
```

The other available option is: `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.

I want to be able to support filenames with unicode characters, and I am not sure if I should compile with the `multi-byte` character set and use all the Wide Character methods, or if I should compile with the `unicode` character set and use all the ASCII methods.

Comment: compile with unicode characters and always use Wide Character methods - ASCII methods is shell over it

Comment: Legacy Win32 APIs use ANSI, not ASCII.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am not sure if I should compile with the multi-byte character set
>   and use all the Wide Character methods, or if I should compile with
>   the unicode character set and use all the ASCII methods.

- If want to use Unicode, you must use the the wide "W" version
  of the functions along with `wchar_t`.
- If you want to use multi-byte character set (MBCS), you must use the the "A" version of the functions with `char`.
- The "A" version of the functions generally do not support all the Unicode characters and essentially widen their input parameter using `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP)`, call their "W" counterpart, and finally transform the result back into multi-byte using `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP)`.

Thus, I would advise you to use the "W" version of the functions assuming you are coding for Windows NT and above.

In the context of the Win32 API, Microsoft's "Unicode" generally refers to UTF-16.
Also Microsoft's MBCS is essentially DBCS and for Windows 9x operating systems, the "W" version of the functions are missing.

Comment: Microsoft shipped the [Microsoft Layer for Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Layer_for_Unicode) for the Win9x line of products, so that you can access the wide character versions of the API.

Comment: @IInspectable, That's great to have. Still I think it is better be aware about a pitfall when you are starting something new. :)

Comment: If you feel the compelling need to comment on operating system, that have been out of mainstream and extended support for well over a decade, at least exercise diligence. While the OS doesn't implement the wide character versions, they are still available through the SDK. Personally, I don't believe that any of that is needed anyway. Besides, Microsoft's Unicode does not refer to UTF-16. The system implements Unicode, and uses UTF-16 or UTF-8 character encodings, depending on who you're asking.

Comment: @IInspectable: Nothing in the Win32 API uses UTF-8 (except for `MultiByteToWideChar`/`WideCharToMultiByte` when using the `CP_UTF8` codepage).  Modern usage of Unicode in Windows DOES refer to UTF-16 only.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The entire .NET metadata, and - by re-use - the Windows Runtime metadata, is encoded using UTF-8. There is quite a bit of UTF-8 encoded data that arrives at the API surface, although the native string type ([HSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br205775.aspx)) still uses UTF-16LE.

Comment: @IInspectable: .NET is not Win32, and metadata is not APIs.  In Win32 APIs and .NET APIs, Unicode strings are UTF-16 encoded, there are no UTF-8 encoded string types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I never claimed that any of this were limited to the Windows API. I specifically said *"the system"*. The Windows Runtime *is* the new programming interface, and metadata *does* show up at the API surface.

Comment: @IInspectable: the question is tagged [tag:winapi], which only applies to the Win32 API. WinRT is covered by the [tag:windows-runtime] tag.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I have been commenting on *"Microsoft's 'Unicode' generally refers to UTF-16."*, which used to read *"[...] UCS-2"*. It was edited from very wrong to wrong. Microsoft is more than Windows or the Windows API. That statement is still wrong, and with all the noise you have done nothing to change, or even acknowledge that.

Comment: I suggest changing that sentence to _"In the context of the Win32 API, Microsoft's "Unicode" generally refers to UTF-16."_

Comment: @zett42 Done as requested. Hopefully this calms everything down. :)